# projectreactor slow consumer protection

Tags: flux, project-reactor

I wanted to use projectreator.io TopicProcessor Flux for publishing market data events to several subscribers. If one client is slow the buffer will get full and it will block the publisher completely. I read about onBackpressureBuffer but I don't think this is the solution.
The best would be that I get a callback and/or the subscriber gets disconnected - how can I achieve this?

Hope that somebody can help.

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: And why is `onBackpressureBuffer` not applicable to your situation?

Comment: I don't think it would work that way. There is the topic-publisher and a couple of subscribers processing market data. So if on of these subscriber blocks for any reason, how should it ever notify upstream about backpressure if it never returns or returns after too long time?

Comment: I see. There are some operators that allow you to limit the throughput. Would that be an option or do you actually need a dynamic solution?

Comment: I'm don't think that would really help. If one subscriber gets stuck there should be either: a) kick out the subscriber or b) have some buffer overflow strategy that events get discarded for that specific subscriber and some callback notification. In any case the other subscribers should never be impacted by the failing one. Is sth like this not foreseen in the reactor?